# Creating dynamic regex match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to define a new regex character pattern in JavaScript with NodeJS? For example, a turning `/hello\sworld/gm` into `/{message}/gm`, where `{message}` is interpreted to match "hello world" or whatever other string I decide.

Essentially I'm trying to avoid this:

```
var message = "hello world";    
(new RegExp(message, "gm")).test(someString);
```

In hopes of getting something like:

```
/{message}/gm.test(someString);
```

I'd like to note that it shouldn't work for only the `test` method. Any method that RegExp uses to match, test, search, etc, should all work. I imagine this would be possible to do if there is a way to override the functions? Or is there a way to edit the RegExp arguments on object creation?

The idea is for me to define `{message}` as meaning something, and for that to be interpreted globally without having to deal with concatenating a variable into every regex pattern.

I am aware that others have asked about dynamic regexps before. The answer to all of those is to use the RegExp constructor. I am wondering if there is an alternative, possibly like overriding vanilla JavaScript classes.

Also note that I'm not asking whether or not this is good practice. I'm asking whether or not it is possible *with or without* good practice in mind.

---

For clarity, `{message}` should be replaced in every single regex made in any file. So `/{message}/` and `/bananas:\s{message}/` become `/hello\sworld/` and `/bananas:\shello\sworld/` respectively, etc etc.

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid this" Why? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski it's messy. I have code stretching multiple files, and in order to do that I'd need to pass my "message" as an argument into every function that uses regex everywhere. On top of that, i'm writing a node module, so all the uses that use my module would also have to do that. It would be easier if everyone could rely on the fact that `{message}` was simply (magically) interpreted to mean a defined value.

Comment: Can't you just assign that regex to a variable and export it?

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps I was a bit unclear, the actual regex doesn't need to be exactly the same. Everywhere in every regex that is created, `{message}` should be replaced with the defined value. So `/{message}/` or `/bananas:\s{message}/` or whatever else you can think of.

Comment: I really don't understand why it would be messier one way or the other: in both cases you would have a string, and in both cases it needs conversion to a regex. I don't see how the syntax you propose could make such a difference. Please provide a concrete example of supposed messiness.

Comment: @trincot I'm not sure what you mean. The standard approach forces you to account for the "message" in everything. If you have a trivial method that checks a string against a regex buried within a class within a class within a class, you have to pass the message parameter down 4 layers of abstraction. I'm trying to get to a state where you don't have to worry about the value of "message" at all. You can construct whatever regex you'd like, and have the confidence of knowing that if `{message}` appears somewhere in the pattern, it will be parsed to the global (possibly dynamic) "message".

Comment: @trincot It's more for anyone else who utilizes the code. I don't want them to have to worry about making sure to `+ message +` in their regexes. Call it laziness or whatever you want, I'm just interested in whether or not it is possible.

Comment: I still don't understand. Please provide example code that illustrates your concern. If your question is *only* to know whether it is possible, then the answer is: no. But if you want some people here to look at your actual use case, I am quite sure we can propose alternatives which are not messy.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The best you can do is create a function which will take a string, replace `{message}`, create a `RegExp` object and return it.